# Error 404 on logfile endpoint when the spring boot application is deployed on Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a simple spring boot application written for a REST API. I am trying to use logback for logs into a file. It works ok when the application is deployed within eclipse on my windows machine and I can see all my logs on /logfile endpoint.

when I deploy the same application on a Linux box , the logfile is created and updated as expected however when I try to access the logfile over the browser,I get a 404 on the same endpoint(/logfile).

Any help will be much appreciated

My logback configuration is as below

logback-spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="api.controllers" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
 </configuration>
```

My application.properties file looks like

```
    server.contextPath=/api
#Configure Access Logs
server.tomcat.basedir=log
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)

#configure other log
logging.file=log/vixenapi.log 
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
#-------------------------------------

spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_empty

#By Default include all properties. If a view property hasn't been set then it will be shown 
spring.jackson.mapper.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION=true
```

The Log file records the exceptions as

```
 : Before request [uri=/com.causeway.vixen.api/logfile;client=172.16.4.56]
2017-11-16 18:29:13.662 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/com.causeway.vixen.api/logfile]
2017-11-16 18:29:13.662 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/com.causeway.vixen.api/logfile] is: -1
2017-11-16 18:29:13.663  WARN 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Locations list is empty. No resources will be served unless a custom ResourceResolver is configured as an alternative to PathResourceResolver.
2017-11-16 18:29:13.663 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-11-16 18:29:13.663 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-11-16 18:29:13.663 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : After request [uri=/com.causeway.vixen.api/logfile;client=172.16.4.56]
2017-11-16 18:29:13.663 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/com.causeway.vixen.api/error]
2017-11-16 18:29:13.664 DEBUG 1552 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
```

Here is my minimal example
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/files/1482233/test_api.zip

Comment: It's very hard to say why this could be happening from your description alone. The logging enpoint tests that are part of the Spring Boot build run on Linux so I think this is something specific to your environment. Checking the user/file permissions of the log file might be a good place to start. Failing that I'd suggest providing [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @PhilWebb thanks for your reply. I have checked all the permissions and they are all ok (777)

Comment: I have checked the file permissions etc and they all look good. I have added excerpts from the log above.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Judging by the log output, it would appear that you're on 1.4.0 or earlier. If you were on 1.4.1 or later [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/3570f7730ab242667731a68061e4434d050c5b70#diff-62678a8065fecf78e011449de210652f) should mean that warning about the empty locations list does not occur.

Comment: Also, your configuration and the request you're making don't seem to match up. The context path is `/api` but the log output shows a request being made to `/com.causeway.vixen.api`. It's going to be hard to make progress without the [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that Phil already requested.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I on 1.4.0 but I am now on 1.5.8 with no change in the outcome. with regards to the context path I had changed it to /com.causeway.. I have a complete and minimal example but not sure how to send it to you.

Comment: I have now manage to upload an example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/files/1482233/test_api.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trailing space in the value of the `logging.file` property in both your minimal example and the configuration in your question. The value in the question is `"log/vixenapi.log "` and it should be `"log/vixenapi.log"`.

You can confirm the problem by enabling debug logging for `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc`. `LogFileMvcEndpoint` will log a message when the log file doesn't exist that includes the path that was checked:

```
2017-11-17 14:40:24.801 DEBUG 30140 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.a.endpoint.mvc.LogFileMvcEndpoint  : Log file 'file [/Users/awilkinson/Downloads/test_api/log/test.log ]' does not exist
```

Note the trailing space at the end of the path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now feel like an idiot. I did see that space but didn't think much of it as Eclipse was trimming it for me. This is now fixed. How do you switch on the debug logging ? Many Thanks.

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc=DEBUG` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: Many Thanks. You are a real star.